# How do i change one item in my image to a specific RGB color? (photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image of a sink. I want to change the color of the sink to a specific RGB color, how do I do that?

Comment: Hi yael, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Coudl you please post an example picture? That might help lots. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the sink is in silvery color (colorless), then you can colorize it by placing the object layer of the same shape as sink in preferred color above, and then just select multiply or overlay method of the blending mode.

That is in short. If you provide us with more info, we can answer you a lot more.

Hope this guidelines can help.

P.S. You can colorize any silver object this way.